# WPF Multiple Screens - Can't position window on secondary monitor when WorkingArea.Left is a negative value

Tags: c#, wpf

**Update:** It was an internal problem. I created a fresh WPF app and tried multi monitor setup with borderless, noresize, nomove window. It all worked fine.

The problem occurs if you're parenting your window to the Desktop. I will inspect further and update this question.

**Original Question:**

I'm setting `Window.Left` and `Window.Top` to `WorkingArea.Left` and `WorkingArea.Top` which I get using `System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens`. The window is borderless, noresize, nomove window with a fixed width. By setting these values I anchor the window to the left edge of the screen. I need to be able to do this on multiple monitors but I can't get it to work.

I have a `ComboBox` where you can select the monitor you want the window to appear on. Once the user selects the monitor, I read its `WorkingArea.Left` and `WorkingArea.Top` values and position my window accordingly.

I have a 2 monitors. When the primary monitor is the one on the left, the coordinates I get using WorkingArea are `WorkingArea.Left = 0` for the left (primary) monitor and `WorkingArea.Left = 1920` for the right (secondary monitor). Positioning works properly.

However, when the primary monitor is the one on the right, the now secondary left monitor reports `WorkingArea.Left = -1920`. When I set `Window.Left` to that value, my window just disappears.

Here is the monitor setup:

[image]

I tried adding different values to Window.Left such as moving it with increments of 128 pixels, I do manage to get it to show on the Secondary Left monitor once it reaches `Window.Left = 0` but it can never show on the Primary Right monitor. At `WorkingArea.Left = 1792`, the edge of my window shows on the primary right monitor, but once it hits 1920 it disappears again.

Why can't I reposition the window to a negative value when the monitor reports a negative `WorkingArea.Left`?

Why would `WorkingArea.Left = 0` show the window on the left edge of the Secondary Left monitor when the `WorkingArea.Left` reported for that monitor is -1920?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I could imagine, that winforms and wpf use different screen coordinates. Have you tried to print out your Window's position on the desired screen? The [SystemParameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.systemparameters?view=net-5.0) class hase some properties you could use but not all that winforms Screen class has.

Comment: ```SystemParameters.VirtualScreenLeft``` reports the same value as ```WorkingArea.Left``` depending on where the primary monitor is. Reports -1920 when Primary monitor is on the right and 0 when Primary monitor is on the left.

Comment: Have you solved your problem? It's just the algebraic sign which you must ignore. The sign only indicates the position relative to the primary screen. If you want to position an object in the top left corner of a screen other than the primary screen (which could be located left to the primary screen), always use absolute coordinates (`Math.Abs`): `var secondaryScreenTopLeft = new Point(Math.Abs(WorkingArea.Left), Math.Abs(WorkingArea.Top))`. In your example this would be equal to `var secondaryScreenTopLeft = new Point(1920, 0)`.